# how to maintain android login session

Tags: android, authentication

Hi i've seen several way to maintain a login session in android like using SharedPreferences and Serializable cookies in DefaultHttpClient. 
I have an android app that communicate with my server to retrieve the user's information after they have logged in. I only want the user to login once until the session has expired.

Using the SharedPreferences to store userID and password seems easy but looks insecure for me. I hope anyone with better experience on this to give me some comment on whether SharedPreferences is better or DefaultHttpClient cookies is better ( Or perhaps there is another way of doing this beside this two) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use tokens instead of store those kind of confidential information.
At your server side, check if given data {user and password} are corrects. then generate a unique hash with an expiration date which allows you to identify the user at your app.

Answer (score 0):

You could store it on a Sqlite3 DB encrypted with [SqlCipher](http://sqlcipher.net/downloads/).

A better approach would be to tell your server to implement Oath2 and use tokens insted of credentials for authentication